# Magento 2 customer address book Call to a member function getFrontendLabel() issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Customer is unable to update and add address in Magento 2.2.6 version.

**Steps to reproduce**

1.Login as customer and click to Address book section.
2.Fatal error will be generate customer is unable to update their address.

[image]

**** Solution ****
Magento 2.2.5 has solution only copy and past the edit.phtml file from Magento 2.2.5 version.
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Change on Layout (example : multishipping_checkout_customer_address.xml etc ) Address edit block on your theme passing below arguments (example: attribute_data and post_code_config).

```
 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
     <arguments>
          <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
          <argument name="post_code_config" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\PostCodesPatternsAttributeData</argument>
     </arguments>
 </block>
```